# Why didn't God speak to the waters to subside in Genesis 8:1?

Tags: genesis, creation, flood

After the flood when God wanted the waters to subside he sent the wind to that

KJV Genesis 8 : 1

> And God remembered Noah, and every living thing, and all the cattle that was with him in the ark: and God made a wind to pass over the earth, and the waters assuaged.

Prior to that during creation when God was creating moving things and separating the waters above from those below he spoke directly to the waters.

KJV Genesis 1 : 20

> And God said, Let the waters bring forth abundantly the moving creature that hath life, and fowl that may fly above the earth in the open firmament of heaven.

KJV Genesis 1 : 9

> And God said, Let the waters under the heaven be gathered together unto one place, and let the dry land appear: and it was so.

Was there something significant why God didn't speak directly to the waters after the flood.

Comment: The wind is of the Spirit and can be addressed reasonably. The waters are the nations and cannot be remonstrated with. But this is a matter of interpretation of symbolism, not plain exegesis. So, a comment, not an answer. I believe in the historical fact of the global flood. But there is also symbolism employed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, there is a greater similarity between Gen 1:2 and Gen 8:1 that it first appears:

- the same preposition עַל (al) = "on/over" is used in both places
- the same noun רוּחַ (ruah) = "spirit/wind" is used in both places
- the same noun מַיִם (mayim) = "waters" is used in both places.

Let me set these out to show the similarities more clearly:

Gen 1:2 - ... and the **Spirit/Wind** of **God** was hovering **over** the surface of the **waters**.

Gen 8:1 - ... and **God** caused a **wind/spirit** to pass **over** the earth, and the **water** subsided.

The literary effect is to have Gen 8:1 allude directly to Gen 1:2 as the start of a new creation after the destruction of the earth by flood waters.  Note the other important link - God created the earth originally starting with water in Gen 1; He does the same in Gen 8; but used the same material, water, to destroy the earth.

Peter makes the same point in 2 Peter 3:5, 6 -

> But they deliberately overlook the fact that long ago by God’s word
> the heavens existed and the earth was formed out of water and by
> water, through whichb the world of that time perished in the flood.

Thus, in a sense, God wanted to make a point that the earth, after the flood, was starting again in a manner that reflected Gen 1 in some sense.